# clickhouse:how to avoid DB::Exception: Division by zero in

Tags: clickhouse

how to avoid DB::Exception: Division by zero in clickhouse when I use divide(Decimal v1,Decimal v2) and v2 comes from a subquery.
I tried to use case when v2 = 0 then 0 else divide end but didn't work!

Comment: could you provide your sql-query and ClickHouse version?

Answer (score 1):

Conditional operators (if/case/ternary) always calculate all branches

https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/4411#issuecomment-464329721

https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/1562

Answer (score 0):

I avoided division by zero using **standard CASE WHEN**:

```
CASE WHEN Quantity > 0 THEN Quantity ELSE 1 END
```

**or ClickHouse function**:

```
multiIf(Quantity > 0, Quantity, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need integer result, you might consider use [`intDivOrZero` function](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/arithmetic-functions#intdivorzeroa-b).